# Natural Map to Singular Construction in Motivic Homotopy Theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

I'm following [*A primer for unstable motivic homotopy theory*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00929) written by Antieau, Elmanto as my first intro to motivic homotopy theory. Their treatment of the singular construction on p. 30 confuses me. Let me introduce you to their setup:

We write $\mathbf{sPre}(\mathbf{Sm}_S) = \operatorname{Fun}(\mathbf{Sm}_S, \mathbf{sSet})$ where $\mathbf{Sm}_S$ is the category of nice enough smooth $S$-schemes. Moreover, we set $\Delta^n = \operatorname{Spec} k[x_0, \cdots, x_n]/(x_0+\cdots+x_n-1)$ which gets promoted to a cosimplicial scheme. Then, we define $$ \operatorname{Sing}^{\mathbb{A}^1} : \mathbf{sPre}(\mathbf{Sm}_S) \to \mathbf{sPre}(\mathbf{Sm}_S), \ X \mapsto |X(- \times \Delta^{\bullet})|. $$ We write $\operatorname{map}$ for the simplicial mapping spaces on the simplicial model categories that are floating around.

There should be a natural map $X \to \operatorname{Sing}^{\mathbb{A}^1} X$. On p. 30 they then write:

> Observe that the functor $U \mapsto X(U \times_S \Delta^n)$ is the same as the functor $U \mapsto \operatorname{map}( \times_S \Delta^n, X)$. We have a natural map $X \simeq \operatorname{map}(\Delta^0, X) \to \operatorname{map}(\Delta^n, X)$ for each $n$, so we think of the map $X \to \operatorname{Sing}^{\mathbb{A}^1}X$ as the canonical map from the zero simplices.

I'm confused about the entire paragraph. Shouldn't it be $\operatorname{map}(\Delta^0, X) \simeq X(\Delta^0)$ and how does this discussion even yield the desired map?

Some remarks that you don't need to read to answer my question:

- Formally, the Yoneda embedding induces for $\Delta^{\bullet} : \Delta \to \mathbf{Sm}_S$ an adjunction $$|-|_{\Delta^{\bullet}} : \mathbf{sSet} \rightleftarrows \mathbf{Sm}_S : \operatorname{Sing}_{\Delta^{\bullet}}$$ but this is not our $\operatorname{Sing}^{\mathbb{A}^1}$.
- The way I understood this $\mathrm{Sing}^{\mathbb{A}^1}$ is as the composition \begin{align*} \mathbf{Sm}_S^{\mathrm{op}} &\to \operatorname{Fun}(\Delta, \mathbf{Sm}_S^{\mathrm{op}}) \to \operatorname{Fun}(\Delta, \mathbf{sSet}) \to \mathbf{sSet}, \\ Y &\mapsto Y \times \Delta^{\bullet} \mapsto X(Y \times \Delta^{\bullet}) \mapsto |X(Y \times \Delta^{\bullet})| = \operatorname{colim}_{n \in \Delta} X(Y \times \Delta^n).\end{align*} But perhaps I misunderstood.

Since the singular construction sounds like a very important construction in the theory, it would be helpful for me to understand it properly, so I'm grateful for any help or comments!

Comment: Maybe the $\Delta^0$ in $X \simeq \operatorname{map}(\Delta^0, X)$ is the constant presheaf at $\Delta^0$ and not the presheaf represented by the scheme $\Delta^0$. I could probably define a morphism then.

Comment: The identity $X(U \times_S \Delta^n) = \mathrm{map}(U \times_S \Delta^n,X)$ is Yoneda embedding while the natural map $\mathrm{map}(\Delta^0,X) \longrightarrow \mathrm{map}(\Delta^n,X)$ is just functoriality.

Comment: Note: In his ICM address Voevodsky defines $\operatorname{Sing}_{\bullet}(X)(U) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Spc}}(U \times \Delta^{\bullet}_S, X) \in \mathbf{sSet}$ with a slightly different setup.

Comment: For any simplicial set $X$, there is an identification $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(\Delta^0,X)\simeq X$, where $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}$ is the internal Hom in simplicial sets. Indeed, as Alexey Do already intimated, this just follows as there is a functorial identification

$$\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(\Delta^0,X)(\Delta^n)=\mathrm{Hom}(\Delta^0\times\Delta^n,X)\simeq \mathrm{Hom}(\Delta^n,X)\simeq X(\Delta^n).$$

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes, thanks (and also thanks to Alexey Do). Points of confusions maybe arise because $X$ is not a simplicial set and there are different possibilities of interpreting what $\Delta^n$ means: Either the constant presheaf at the simplicial set $\Delta^n$ or the presheaf represented by the scheme $\Delta^n$ (hence my first comment). But the main point for me remains how the quote relates to the natural map $X \to \operatorname{Sing}^{\mathbb{A}^1}X$. Thanks for your comments!